# Pass selected value dropdownlist to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a viewbag to list some data from table. and represent in view like this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("GetControllerID", new SelectList(ViewBag.GetController, "", ""), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn-default btn input-circle"})
```

how can i pass the selected value to controller?

```
ViewBag.GetControllerID = new SelectList(ListLogs.Where(o => o.CreateDate.Month == DateTime.UtcNow.Month && o.CreateDate.Year == DateTime.UtcNow.Year).ToList());
```

Comment: The name attribute on the control is the variable name used to store the information when passed to the controller.

Comment: ViewBag only takes data from the Controller to the View. Not the other way around.

Comment: What? What does that second line show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, as you **submit the form**, you can `catch the selected value` in the controller `through the name property` you set for that element.

In this case, in the controller you can have:

```
string selectedValue = this.HttpContext.Request.Form["GetControllerID"].ToString();
```

However, if you have a complex form, I recommend you create a **ViewModel** and pass the form values to the controller through it. Here is a nice simple thread:

- https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MVC-Form-Submit-Post-example.aspx

Comment: If your dropdown is a `multiselect`, you can retrieve it this way: `var x = this.HttpContext.Request.Form["GetControllerID"]?.Where(i => i.ToString() != ",").ToList();`